# Notification icon configured for MobilePush on Android, yet it's not displayed

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, android

We can't seem to get Marketing Cloud (MobilePush) to display the icon we've configured it to display on Android. As far as I can tell, we've followed [the documentation](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/notifications/customize-notifications.html#full-control-customization) correctly, but the system default notification icon is still displayed. Using our own custom push notification handling (for handling non-MobilePush push notifications) shows the correct icon, which is using the same drawable resource.

We're using version 8.0.4 of the SDK (com.salesforce.marketingcloud:marketingcloudsdk:8.0.4).

Here's how we've configured the SDK:

**Configuring `SFMCSdk` (stripped for brevity):**

```kotlin
val sdkModuleConfig = SFMCSdkModuleConfig.build {
  pushModuleConfig = MarketingCloudConfig.builder()
    .setNotificationCustomizationOptions(
      NotificationCustomizationOptions.create { context, notificationMessage ->
        NotificationManager.getDefaultNotificationBuilder(
          context,
          notificationMessage,
          NotificationManager.createDefaultNotificationChannel(context),
          R.drawable.ic_notification, // <-- this icon is not displayed in notifications
        )
          .setContentIntent(
            NotificationManager.redirectIntentForAnalytics(
              context,
              buildNotificationIntent(notificationMessage.url),
              notificationMessage,
              true, // dismiss after opening
            ),
          )
      },
  )
}

SFMCSdk.configure(application, sdkModuleConfig) {
  // handle initialization status
}
```

**Receiving push notifications:**

```kotlin
SFMCSdk.requestSdk { sdk ->
  sdk.mp { mp ->
    mp.pushMessageManager.handleMessage(remoteMessage)
  }
}
```

Any steps to guide us in the right direction would be appreciated! ☺

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found that working with WebP assets were the issue, even though WebP is supported by the system. Converting the WebP graphics to PNGs made them appear also using MobilePush.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that can make the icon not display correctly is it being invalid with regards to Google's requirements.  See Google's notification icon requirements.  Also, search for Android Asset Studio.  It's a great tool for creating all sorts of Android assets.

Comment: I don't understand how that could be the case, though, as it's being shown for non-MobilePush push notifications and we're using the exact same asset there through `NotificationCompat.Builder#setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)`.

Comment: There is no "magic" in the SDK in this regard: `builder.setSmallIcon(smallIconResId)` and we have thousands of customers using this version with hundreds of millions of installed devices.  Check your asset.

Comment: We were using WebP assets. I noticed that your sample application had PNG assets. WebP worked fine through `NotificationCompat.Builder`, but not with SFMCSdk. Converting those same assets from WebP to PNG worked with MobilePush as well. Are you sure there's no file type check anywhere preventing WebP images from working?

Comment: The SDK simply assigns the `smallIcon` just as you see above.

Comment: Very strange. We're using `NotificationCompat` from androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0. Perhaps there's a difference there. Either way, it doesn't matter anymore, we converted to a PNG and now it works with both SDKs.